# Package type definition cannot be found

Tags: typescript, xlsx-js

I am working on a AngularJS project using typescript.  I am trying to use the `js-xlsx` library to parse an xlsx file and I get the compile error:

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XLSX'`

We are using a global namespace for all files and all the compiled files get concatenated because of the `outFile` compiler option.  No module system is configured and we include all our JavaScript dependencies in the `index.html` file.  We therefore do not `import` any modules.

All other dependencies up to this point have type definitions installed under `node_modules/@types` and are correctly recognized by the compiler as explained [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types).

The `js-xlsx` however includes the type definitions in the package, i.e `node_modules/xlsx/types/index.d.ts` but this is not *automatically* picked up by the compiler.

Unfortunately I cannot change the project structure and module system.  How do I get the typescript compiler to recognize the type definitions of the `xlsx` package so that I can do:

```
onload(event: any) {
  let workbook = XLSX.read(event.target.result, {type: "binary"});
}
```

without getting compiler errors and get *intellisense/code completion* in VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a global definition that exposes the module as a global variable.

Save the `index.d.js` in any location in your project as `js-xlsx.d.ts`

In the same location add a file `js-xlsx-global.d.ts`

```
import * as xlsx from './js-xlsx'

declare global {
    export var XLSX: typeof xlsx;
}
```

Now you can use `///` references in files to get the `XLSX` variable to type correctly

```
/// <reference path="./js-xlsx-global.d.ts" />

XLSX.read(null, { type: "binary"}); // works, and is checked.
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.  I made some minor changes by adding a file ```xlsx.shim.d.ts``` to my project and adding:
```import * as xlsx from 'xlsx'

declare global {
    export var XLSX: typeof xlsx;
}``` to the content

Also added triple slash directive to use in my code